# How to Convert list to string and keep the 'quotes'

Tags: python

I have the following list :

```
StringTest = ['A','B','C','D']
```

The output excepted is :

```
"'A','B','C','D'"
```

but it seems that the '' are perma deleted.

Below is the code I tried :

```
StringTest = ['A','B','C','D']
StringTest = ','.join(StringTest )
print(StringTest )
```

which returns :

```
"A,B,C,D"
```

How can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
StringTest = ['A','B','C','D']

print('"'+','.join(f"'{s}'" for s in StringTest)+'"')
```

**Output:**

```
"'A','B','C','D'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)?

```py
print(','.join(map(repr, StringTest)))
# 'A','B','C','D'
print(repr(','.join(map(repr, StringTest)))
# "'A','B','C','D'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to add the commas between each character, and use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) to add the single quotes to each character:

```py
string_test = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
string_test = ",".join(f"'{c}'" for c in string_test)
print(string_test)
```

Output:

`'A','B','C','D'`

See also: [*f-strings*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals)

Answer (score 0):

This is expected operation for string functions. If you want the "'" character included *in* your string, your input string needs to include it like `"'A'"`. There are many ways to do this using string manipulation and iterating thru your input list, e.g.

```
','.join([f"'{each}'" for each in StringTest])
```

As noted below in comments, if you want to embed this string within another set of quotes since the `__str__` will strip them using `print()`, you can:

```
>>> '"{}"'.format(','.join([f"'{each}'" for each in StringTest]))
'"\'A\',\'B\',\'C\',\'D\'"'
>>> print(_)
"'A','B','C','D'"
```

Comment: Misses the leading and trailing quotes

Comment: @Cobra, yes you are right, this answer returns the string. The print() function __str__ strips the quotes but __repr__ doesn't. OP can use this to append/insert another set of trailing/leading quotes if needed. It is certainly more Pythonic this way.

Comment: Whether it's "Pythonic" or not is irrelevant. The simple fact is that the desired result is not output with this code

Answer (score 0):

It seems weird but it is an easy solution anyway:

```
str_edit = '"'+ str(StringTest).replace('[', '').replace(']', '') + '"'
print(str_edit.replace(" ", ''))
```

output:

```
"'A','B','C','D'"
```